# Numbers - continuous line connecting gapped data?

Tags: numbers, iwork

[This question over on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/246614/making-line-charts-so-the-line-goes-through-all-data-points) is exactly the same as mine, in the sense that I have a CSV that contains gaps in each column, but I want to plot it as a continuous line. However, I'm using Numbers, not Excel. Is there a way to replicate those results using Numbers? The `Format` menu doesn't seem to have too many parameters to adjust regarding this.

---

The current workaround I have is to set the graph to "2D Area" ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOkCl.png)), selecting the line itself in the graph, setting `No Fill`, and then setting the `Stroke` parameter. This achieves the intended effect ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PMMR.png)), but doesn't scale well with multiple (overlapping) datasets.

[image: Before, setting the graph to 2D Area]
[image: Afterwards]

---

And here's the data when enabling 2D Line

[image]

Comment: Is the ultimate aim that you actually want to plot the points for which there is no data? Or would it work just as well not plotting those points at all, so long as your line chart is a still a single solid line?

Comment: Have you tried plotting it as a 2d scatter plot?  That may improve your results.

Comment: The idea is that I want to join the points together even across the gaps where there is no data available. Essentially, instead of clusters (like in the bottom image) I want a continuous line

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue. Ideally I would like to change the appearance of the line when it is filling in gaps.

Answer (score 1):

You should plot the data using the 2d Scatter plot. This will draw a continuous line connecting the dta points.

I had some issues with scatter plot in Numbers but eventually got it working. I had problems sometimes getting to to use the correct x and y values. Maybe you won't encounter these issues.

Comment: This still only connects the contiguous data together, rather than all the data

Comment: You need to delete the cells with no data and then it will connect all. You can sort the data on certain fields and this will result in all empty cells being grouped making them easy to delete.